Bypassing a Junit test
Okay, this might seem weird to some (and probably a bad habit) but I was wondering if there was a way to edit my code so that a JUnit test passes no matter what. Half the failures are nonsensical, the due date for this uni thing is in 2 days.
I tried reading into all sorts of resources but found nothing (for good reason, people usually don't want to fake working code), but all the uni does is simply check for the green bar by installing their own clean version of the test file, so changing the test itself is out of the question. Any help would be lifesaving at this rate.

If you cannot add @Ignore to the tests, you'd need to know what the tests are looking for, and then you could return fake / canned answers. But this means you're breaking your code and it won't work for anything but these tests. If the tests really don't make sense, discuss that with the people that insist on these tests. Other than that you'll have to actually implement the desired behavior.

You're unlikely to find people here who want to help you cheat. Your best bet is to figure out why the test is failing and to fix the error(s) in your code. Go to your professor, a teaching assistant, a tutor, or even your classmates for help if you need it.

The thing is some of the requirments are met but the test just up and fails anyway.
worst example of this is a method called IsGameOver(), the method is like 2 lines work, and the actual test for it passes, but then tests that make sure you DONT add extra things to it because...it somehow cant find the method, and throws a NoSuchMethod exception at me.

If you're getting a NoSuchMethodException or a NoSuchMethodError, then it sounds like you're not allowed to change the signatures of the methods you're supposed to implement. In other words, do not change the name or formal parameters of the methods being tested.

Maybe the VW JUnit test package works for you, if you can influence how the tests run. Beware any trailing lawsuits.

It's clear at this point you're asking us to help you cheat.  We won't.  If you think the test failures are nonsensical, that's something to take up with your professor or TA, but it's fairly likely that the failures aren't as nonsensical as you think.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you have write access to the JUnit test files, you can modify the assertions to always pass, such as assertTrue(true). However, if you only have read access, carefully examine each test case and ensure your program produces the expected output values that the tests are checking for.

I technically do have write access, but the guys testing have a clean version, so it would just get overridden and fail anyway, except now I would look hilariously suspecious
